# sql Query support required for condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query if vatgroup chooses `x6` or `x7` in output has to show `'-'` other than than it has to show the value what is come.
Based on below query my output comes as `*` for other than x6 or x7.

```
case when t1.VatGroup in('X6','X7') then '-' 
Else CAST(CAST(sum(t1.vatsum) As Int) AS Varchar(1)) end 'LineVat_LCNew',
```

Thanks
Vinoth

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflucting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting your integer sum to `varchar(1)` which means if the `sum` is greater than 1 digit you won't be able to place then in a `varchar(1)`. Use `varchar(10)` instead which means you can store upto 10 digits.

```
case when t1.VatGroup in('X6','X7') then '-' 
Else CAST(CAST(sum(t1.vatsum) As Int) AS Varchar(10)) end 'LineVat_LCNew'
```

Comment: vat value is not showing full decimals. Its rounded. how to enable with full decimals. IF other than X6 or X7 decimal is not showing fully

Comment: that's because you are casting the sum to `int` first. Cast it to  [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead

Comment: Yes the below decimal applied and solved                                                                  case when t1.VatGroup in('X6','X7') then '-' Else CAST(CAST(sum(t1.vatsum) As decimal(8,6)) AS varchar(max)) end 'LineVat_LCNew',